# flutter Login authentication ba,how can i call refresh token api to get new token ?, how can i pass API key and Token to used in all other API’s

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, flutter-dependencies

At the time of login, you will get an API key and Token. This API key and Token must be used in all other API’ s and The token obtained will get expired within a specific time, so you must call a refresh token API to get new token.

How can i implement this question in the login function..?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<dynamic> login(String username, String password) async {
  var client = http.Client();

  var response = await client.post(
      Uri.parse('https://flutter.noviindus.co.in/api/LoginApi'),
      body: {'username': username, 'password': password},
      headers: {});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var refreshToken = data['refresh'];
    print(refreshToken);
  }
}
```

i try to pass the token in headers

Answer (score 0):

I have a network manager using Dio package, It will handle the refresh token functionality also, just change the base url. I have implement the logging of the request and response, if you don't want it, remove the colorize and its implementations. Cheers.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:colorize/colorize.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

import '../navigation/navigation_constants.dart';

// Local manager is a custom wrapper for Sharedpreference,
// You can use your own method of getting the values from Shareprefs

class NetworkManager {
  static Dio createDio() {
    String baseURL = ApplicationConstants.BASEURL;

    BaseOptions opts = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseURL,
      responseType: ResponseType.json,
      connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
      contentType: "application/json",
      receiveTimeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
    );

    return Dio(opts);
  }

  static Dio addInterceptors(Dio dio) {
    return dio
      ..interceptors.addAll([
        InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (options, handler) {
          String token =
              LocalManager.instance.getStringValue(PreferencesKeys.token);
          if(token != ""){
            options.headers.addAll({"Authorization": "Bearer $token"});
          }
          return handler.next(options); //continue
        }, onResponse: (response, handler) async {
          Colorize string = Colorize(
                  "Response | Status code:${response.statusCode.toString()}")
              .bold()
              .cyan();
          print(string);
          return handler.next(response); // continue
        }, onError: (DioError e, handler) async {
          /// Get Retry Limit
          /// Default: 1
          int retryCount = LocalManager.instance.getRetryCount();
          Colorize string = Colorize(
                  "Response | Status code:${e.response?.statusCode.toString()}")
              .cyan();
          print(string);

          /// Refresh token
          if (e.response?.statusCode == 401 && retryCount > 0) {
            String refToken =
                LocalManager.instance.getStringValue(PreferencesKeys.refreshToken);

            Colorize string = Colorize(
                    "Refreshing | Status code:${e.response?.statusCode.toString() ?? "EMPTY"}")
                .red();
            print(string);

            LocalManager.instance.setRetryCount(0);

            /// Requesting new token
            Response tokenResp = await tokenDio
                .post("auth/refreshtoken", data: {"refreshToken": refToken});

            switch (tokenResp.statusCode) {
              case 200:
                var token = tokenResp.data["jwt"];
                var refreshToken = tokenResp.data["refreshToken"];
                LocalManager.instance
                    .setStringValue(PreferencesKeys.token, token);
                LocalManager.instance
                    .setStringValue(PreferencesKeys.refreshToken, refreshToken);

                /// Resetting retry count
                LocalManager.instance.setRetryCount(1);
                break;
              default:
                return handler.next(e);
            }

            /// Creating options and request object to retry the request which was failed previously
            final options = Options(
              method: e.requestOptions.method,
              headers: e.requestOptions.headers,
            );
            var req = dio.request<dynamic>(e.requestOptions.path,
                data: e.requestOptions.data,
                queryParameters: e.requestOptions.queryParameters,
                options: options);

            /// Retrying request
            return handler.resolve(await req);
          } else if (e.response?.statusCode == 404 || e.response?.statusCode == 400) {
            return handler.next(e);
          } else if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
            /// Reset the local storage
            LocalManager.instance.clearAll();

            /// Navigate the user to Login screen
            NavigationService.instance
                .navigateToPageClear(NavigationConstants.root);
          }

          return handler.next(e);
        }),
        LoggingInterceptors()
      ]);
  }

  /// Token [Dio] is used to get new token without Token
  static Dio tokenDio = createDio();

  /// Main [Dio] object
  static Dio dio = createDio();

  /// Adding Interceptors to the Main [Dio]
  static final baseAPI = addInterceptors(dio);

  switchUrl() {
    String baseURL = LocalManager.instance.getBoolValue(PreferencesKeys.SWITCH)
        ? ApplicationConstants.LOCAL_URL
        : ApplicationConstants.STAGE_URL;

    tokenDio.options.baseUrl = baseURL;
    dio.options.baseUrl = baseURL;
  }

  Future<Response> get(String url) async {
    try {
      Response response = await baseAPI.get(url);
      return response;
    } on DioError {
      rethrow;
    } on TimeoutException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<Response> post(String url, dynamic data) async {
    try {
      Response response = await baseAPI.post(url, data: data);
      return response;
    } on DioError {
      rethrow;
    } on TimeoutException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<Response> put(String url, dynamic data) async {
    try {
      Response response = await baseAPI.put(url, data: data);
      return response;
    } on DioError {
      rethrow;
    } on TimeoutException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<Response> delete(String url) async {
    try {
      Response response = await baseAPI.delete(url);
      return response;
    } on DioError {
      rethrow;
    } on TimeoutException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  toJson(data) {
    JsonEncoder encoder = const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
    String prettyprint = encoder.convert(data);
    log(prettyprint);
  }

}
```